# How to modify context menu in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

Does anyone know how to modify the CKEditor right-click contex menu?

I am trying to figure out how to remove "Cut, Copy, Paste, Edit DIV" from the right-click menu, and trying to add "Insert Image, Insert Table" to it.

Comment: I'm also looking for this, any updates? perhaps post the answer if you found one?

Comment: Does anyone find answer for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Version 3.6.1 has support in their API for removing context menu items.

[#7885](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7885) : New [editor::removeMenuItem](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#removeMenuItem) API for removing plugin context menu items introduced.

Comment: How to add menu item in context menu such as bold, italic etc?